# Group DataSet Column Values into Comma Separated String using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

How do I combine column values in a dataset using LINQ into a single string with comma separated values in VB.NET ?

I have one table with following structure

```
ID        Name
728       Jim
728       Katie
728       Rich
```

How do I combine these into a single row like following

```
ID   Name
728  Jim,Katie,Rich
```

Please note I am using a LINQ to Dataset so please respond in the applicable syntax.

Comment: You want to include "ID Name" as part of the string?  Your question is not very clear.  Why is Rich included in the string, even though he as a different ID?

Comment: Yes, all of them have the same ID. I have edited it. The formatting got mesed up. It should be in a table. ID and Name are columns in the table.

Comment: That's not the answer I am looking for. I know that I could use string.join but I want the associated LINQ query using group By in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (using LINQ to objects, but should be easy to adjust for LINQ to DataSet):

```
Class Record
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property Name As String
  Sub New(id As Integer, name As String)
    Me.ID = id
    Me.Name = name
  End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
  Dim recordList As New List(Of Record)

  recordList.Add(New Record(728, "Jim"))
  recordList.Add(New Record(728, "Katie"))
  recordList.Add(New Record(728, "Rich"))

  recordList.Add(New Record(729, "John"))
  recordList.Add(New Record(729, "Michael"))

  Dim v = From r As Record In recordList
          Group By ID = r.ID Into Records = Group
          Select ID, Name = String.Join(","c, Records.Select(Function(x) x.Name))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
Dim result = list.GroupBy(Function(a) a.ID) _
.Select(Function(g) New With {.ID = g.Key, .csvList = g.Select(Function(n) n.Name) _ 
.Aggregate(Function(accumulation, current) accumulation + "," + current)}) _
.ToList()
```

Comment: If you're going to use nested Lambdas in VB, you could at least have the courtesy to put some line breaks in there so we can read what the heck is going on.

Comment: Gotcha, just put them in

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using LINQ to Dataset:

```
Dim grouped =
    From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
    Group row By id = row.Field(Of Integer)("ID") Into Group
    Select ID, Name = String.Join(",", From i In Group Select i.Field(Of String)("Name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty late but i also ran into same problem and this is my solution. Hope this helps someone

```
 Dim grouped = 
        a.AsEnumerable().
          GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("ID")).
          Select(Function(group, ID)
                     Return New With
                     {
                         .ID= ID,
                         .Name= String.Join(",", group.Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Name")))
                     }
                 End Function)
```